# Problems with Raspberry Pi and Arduino Robot

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

Hi I'm having trouble controlling a robot wirelessly from my PC using a wired Xbox controller. The robot is controlled with a Raspberry Pi 3 and an Arduino. The Pi communicates with my PC over wifi using python 2.7's socket library and then writes the data to the serial port on the Arduino to control the motors.

My problem is trying to send the data from my PC to the Pi. My PC will send the data using the socket library and the Pi will receive it, but when I send a lot of inputs, like from the analog stick on the Xbox controller, the Pi concatenates all of the data together. For example when I send 255, 150, and 10 the Pi will receive 25515010 which isn't correct. Also when sending a lot of data the Pi will freeze up and quit receiving data for some reason.

To fix the concatenating problem I added in a delay to my code which sort of fixes the problem but made the controller slow and unresponsive which I don't want in my robot.

Any and all help is appreciated I am very new to using python and Raspberry Pi's. Thanks!

Here is the code running on my PC.

```
    # This is the server code.
# This is where my PC takes inputs from and Xbox controller and sends them to the Pi.

from __future__ import print_function
from inputs import get_gamepad

import socket
import time

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('192.168.1.17', 8086)

sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

def ArduinoMap(value1, in_min,  in_max,  out_min,  out_max):
    return(value1 - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min

def main():

    X = str(0)
    Y = str(0)
    A = str(0)
    B = str(0)
    LX = str(0)
    LY = str(0)
    RX = str(0)


    while True:


        # Wait for a connection

        connection, client_address = sock.accept()


        try:

            print('Connection from:', client_address)
            last_inputs = '0 0 0 0'

            # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
            while True:
                events = get_gamepad()
                for event in events:

##                    time.sleep(.005) # This is the delay that makes the robot slow and unresponsive

                    if event.code == "ABS_X" or event.code == "ABS_RX" or event.code == "ABS_Y" or event.code == "ABS_RY": #start of deadzone
                        if event.state >= -2550 and event.state <= 2550:
                            event.state=0

                    if event.code == "BTN_WEST": # button X   The X,Y,A,and B button are currently not being used.
                        X = str(event.state)
                        #print(X)
                    elif event.code == "BTN_NORTH": # button Y
                        Y = str(event.state)
                        #print(Y)
                    elif event.code == "BTN_SOUTH": # button A
                        A = str(event.state)
                        #print(A)
                    elif event.code == "BTN_EAST": # button B
                        B = str(event.state)
                        #print(B)
                    elif event.code == "ABS_Y": # left stick Y
                        LY = ArduinoMap(event.state, -32768, 32767, 0, 255)
                        if LY == 127:
                            LY = 0
                        LY = str(LY)
                    elif event.code == "ABS_X": # left stick X
                        LX = ArduinoMap(event.state, -32768, 32767, 0, 255)
                        if LX == 127:
                            LX = 0
                        LX = str(LX)
                    elif event.code == "ABS_RX": # right stick turn
                        RX = ArduinoMap(event.state, -32768, 32767, 0, 255)
                        if RX == 127:
                            RX = 0
                        RX = str(RX)

                    inputs = LY+' '+LX+' '+RX #+' '+X+' '+Y+' '+A+' '+B

                    if inputs != last_inputs:

                        connection.send(inputs)
##                        time.sleep(.001) # This delay also doesn't help
                        print(inputs)

                        last_inputs = inputs

        finally: # Clean up the connection
            print('Keyboard Interrupt')
            connection.close()
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Here is the code running on the Pi

```
    # This is the client code

import serial
import time
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600, timeout = 1) # opening serial port between pi and arduino

server_address = ('192.168.1.17',8086) # computron
#server_address = ('192.168.1.128',8089) # my laptop


sock.connect(server_address)

print'Connecting to:', server_address

last_input = [0, 0, 0, 0]

inputs = 0

try:

    sock.sendall('Starting Connection')



    while True:


        inputs = sock.recv(4096) # receive data from socket


        print(inputs)

        inputs = inputs
        data = inputs.split()# change string into list

        serial.write(str(data)) # write data to Arduino serial port

        print('data', data)

        last_input = inputs

        status = serial.read() # read what the arduino is sending

        #print(status)
        sock.send(str(status))

        waiting = serial.inWaiting()

        if waiting > 2000:

            serial.reset_input_buffer() # clean up serial buffer



finally:
    print('Closing Connection')
    sock.close() # clean up connection
```

Here is the code running on the Arduino:

```
    // 4/3/2018
// Motor control

#include <Wire.h>
//#include <I2CEncoder.h>

const byte numChars = 32;
char data[numChars]; // an array to store received data
char tempData[numChars]; // temoporary array for use by strtok() function

char message[numChars] = {0}; // variables to hold parsed data
int integer;

boolean newData = false;

int motor1dir1 = 8; // Motor 1
int motor1dir2 = 10;
int motor1speed = 9;

int motor2dir1 = 2; // Motor 2
int motor2dir2 = 4;
int motor2speed = 3;

int motor3dir1 = 12; // Motor 3
int motor3dir2 = 13;
int motor3speed = 11;

int motor4dir1 = 6; // Motor 4
int motor4dir2 = 7;
int motor4speed = 5;

int joy1x = A0; // Joy stick for directional movement
int joy1y = A1;
int joy1xx;
int joy1yy;

int joy2x = A2; // Joy stick for rotation
int joy2y = A3;
int joy2xx;
int joy2yy;

int motor1val;
int motor2val;
int motor3val;
int motor4val;
int NSdir;
int EWdir;
int LRdir;

//I2CEncoder Encoder1;
//I2CEncoder Encoder2;
//I2CEncoder Encoder3;
//I2CEncoder Encoder4;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(250000); // start serial comms

  //Wire.begin();


  //Encoder1.init((2.75 / 12)*MOTOR_393_SPEED_ROTATIONS, MOTOR_393_TIME_DELTA);
  //Encoder2.init((2.75 / 12)*MOTOR_393_SPEED_ROTATIONS, MOTOR_393_TIME_DELTA);
  //Encoder3.init((2.75 / 12)*MOTOR_393_SPEED_ROTATIONS, MOTOR_393_TIME_DELTA);
  //Encoder4.init((2.75 / 12)*MOTOR_393_SPEED_ROTATIONS, MOTOR_393_TIME_DELTA);

  pinMode(motor1dir1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor1dir2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor1speed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2dir1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2dir2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2speed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor3dir1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor3dir2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor3speed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor4dir1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor4dir2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor4speed, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(joy1x, INPUT);
  pinMode(joy1y, INPUT);
  pinMode(joy2x, INPUT);
  pinMode(joy2y, INPUT);

  //  if(Serial.available() == 0) // maybe i'll add in a handshake later
  //  {
  //    Serial.write('A');
  //  }

}

void loop() {

  //  joy1xx = analogRead(joy1x);
  //  joy1yy = analogRead(joy1y);
  //
  //  joy2xx = analogRead(joy2x);
  //  joy2yy = analogRead(joy2y);

  dataReceive();
  if (newData == true) {
    strcpy(tempData, data);
    dataParse();
    assignData();
    newData = false;
  }
  if (joy1xx == 127){
    joy1xx = 0;
  }
  joy1xx = integer; // think of better name later

  //Serial.println("here");
  //  joy1yy

  //  joy2yy


  NSdir = map(joy1xx, 0, 255, -255, 255);
  EWdir = map(joy1yy, 0, 255, -255, 255);
  LRdir = map(joy2yy, 0, 255, -255, 255);


  motor1val = NSdir + EWdir + LRdir;
  motor2val = NSdir - EWdir + LRdir;
  motor3val = NSdir + EWdir - LRdir;
  motor4val = NSdir - EWdir - LRdir;

  motor1val = constrain(motor1val, -255, 255);
  motor2val = constrain(motor2val, -255, 255);
  motor3val = constrain(motor3val, -255, 255);
  motor4val = constrain(motor4val, -255, 255);



  if (motor1val < 0)
  {
    motor1val = abs(motor1val);
    analogWrite(motor1speed, motor1val);
    digitalWrite(motor1dir1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor1dir2, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(motor1speed, motor1val);
    digitalWrite(motor1dir1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor1dir2, HIGH);
  }

  if (motor2val < 0)
  {
    motor2val = abs(motor2val);
    analogWrite(motor2speed, motor2val);
    digitalWrite(motor2dir1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor2dir2, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(motor2speed, motor2val);
    digitalWrite(motor2dir1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor2dir2, LOW);
  }

  if (motor3val < 0)
  {
    motor3val = abs(motor3val);
    analogWrite(motor3speed, motor3val);
    digitalWrite(motor3dir1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor3dir2, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(motor3speed, motor3val);
    digitalWrite(motor3dir1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor3dir2, HIGH);
  }

  if (motor4val < 0)
  {
    motor4val = abs(motor4val);
    analogWrite(motor4speed, motor4val);
    digitalWrite(motor4dir1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor4dir2, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    analogWrite(motor4speed, motor4val);
    digitalWrite(motor4dir1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor4dir2, LOW);
  }
}
  void dataReceive()
  {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '\n';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
      rc = Serial.read();

      if (recvInProgress == true) {
        if (rc != endMarker) {
          data[ndx] = rc;
          ndx++;
          if (ndx >= numChars) {
            ndx = numChars - 1;
          }
        }
        else {
          data[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
          recvInProgress = false;
          ndx = 0;
          newData = true;
        }
      }

      else if (rc == startMarker) {
        recvInProgress = true;
      }
    }
  }

  void dataParse() {

    //Serial.print(data);

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempData, ","); // get the string
    strcpy(message, strtokIndx); // store in pasrsedData

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // continue where we left off
    integer = atoi(strtokIndx); // convert to an integer

  }

  void assignData() {
    if (newData == true) {
      //Serial.println(message);
      //    val = map(integer, 0, 255, 0, 180);
      //    myservo.write(val);
      //    Serial.println(val);
      //    val = data;
      //    myservo.write(val);
      //    newData = false;
    }
  }
```

And finally a screen shot of the python shell running on my PC (left) and on my Pi (right).

[The Python shell running on my PC is on the left and the Python shell running on my Pi is on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVJez.png)

Comment: Please offer a _minimal_ working example. This is to much code for such a simple problem.

Comment: Instead of adding a delay, add an extra character at the start and/or end of each number to denote where each one starts or ends.  <255><150><10>

Comment: Like a start and stop bit?